# SMTP not configured, check your grafana.ini config file's [smtp] section

Tags: docker, grafana, grafana-alerts

For notification, I added Notification Channel in Grafana with Type as Email and then click on 'Send Test' button but it gave -

```
SMTP not configured, check your grafana.ini config file's [smtp] section
```

I have installed Grafana as a docker container hence I went inside container and updated `grafana.ini` file with SMTP details and to reflect change, restarted Grafana with -

```
docker restart grafana
```

and now went to Notification Channel and clicked on 'Send Test' but still see same error.

Please help to understand what could be wrong here and which log file(with location ) to check what exactly went wrong here.

Comment: Just in case, I was following this tutorial (https://techexpert.tips/es/grafana-es/configuracion-de-la-notificacion-por-correo-electronico-de-grafana/) and I was getting that message until I realize that in grafana.ini ";" also acts as a comment "#" (check out 2nd lmulligan´s comment on May'17 in https://community.grafana.com/t/smtp-not-configured-check-your-grafana-ini-config-files-smtp-section/1113).

Answer (score 2):

```
All options in the configuration file can be overridden using environment variables using the syntax:

GF_<SectionName>_<KeyName>

Where the section name is the text within the brackets. Everything should be uppercase, . and - should be replaced by _. For example, if you have these configuration settings:

# default section
instance_name = ${HOSTNAME}

[security]
admin_user = admin

[auth.google]
client_secret = 0ldS3cretKey

[plugin.grafana-image-renderer]
rendering_ignore_https_errors = true
You can override them on Linux machines with:

export GF_DEFAULT_INSTANCE_NAME=my-instance
export GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=owner
export GF_AUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=newS3cretKey
export GF_PLUGIN_GRAFANA_IMAGE_RENDERER_RENDERING_IGNORE_HTTPS_ERRORS=true
```

Ref:https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#configure-with-environment-variables

Answer (score -2):

> I went inside container and updated grafana.ini file with SMTP details and to reflect change

That is not correct configuration of containers. Use env variables.

Comment: There documentation mentions to make change in `grafana.ini` https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/ How use of env variables going to help over this? Can you please help me on how to set env variables for SMTP?